# What's wrong with my MYSQL trigger syntax?

Tags: sql, mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER event_house_dealed AFTER UPDATE ON house FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE finished INT;
IF NEW.isdeal = 1 THEN
    SET finished = 1;
END IF;
END;
```

The MySQL server keep saying

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF NEW.isdeal = 1 THEN  SET
>   finished = 1' at line 1

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change delimiter before defining trigger

```
DELIMITER ||
CREATE TRIGGER event_house_dealed AFTER UPDATE ON house FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
DECLARE finished INT;
IF NEW.isdeal = 1 THEN
    SET finished = 1;
END IF;
END||
```

Then of course change the delimiter back to ;

```
DELIMITER ;
```

Same goes for declaring functions and stored procedures